# How to navigate through multiple pages from search in Django?

Tags: python, html, django, django-views

I am trying to create a webpage using Django where my database consists thousands of CVEs and display the list of CVEs based on what I typed in the search bar. So far, the search function is working perfectly and it displays the paginated results. But when I try to navigate to next page, it will show a blank page. Below is the code of my views.py and template.

views.py

```
def search_cve(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        searched = request.GET.get('searched')
        if searched:
            cve_search = BDSA.objects.filter(cve_id__icontains=searched)
            paginator = Paginator(cve_search.order_by('-cve_id'), 10)  # show 10 per page
            try:
                page = int(request.GET.get('page', '1'))
            except:
                page = 1
            try:
                cves = paginator.page(page)
            except:
                cves = paginator.page(1)
            index = cves.number - 1
            max_index = len(paginator.page_range)
            start_index = index - 2 if index >= 2 else 0
            end_index = index + 2 if index <= max_index - 2 else max_index
            page_range = list(paginator.page_range)[start_index:end_index]
            return render(request, 'QueryService/search_cve.html', {'searched':searched, 'cve_search':cve_search, 'cves': cves, 'page_range': page_range})
        else:
            return render(request, 'QueryService/search_cve.html', {})
```

template

```
<body>
{% block content %}
<br/>
<center>
        <h1>Searched for: {{ searched }}</h1>
        <br/>
        <div class="container">
            <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered">
                {% for cve in cves %}
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="{% url 'show-cve' cve.cve_id %}">{{ cve }}</a></td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
        </div>
    <br/>
    <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
        <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
            {% if cves.has_previous %}
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page=1">&laquo; First</a></li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ cves.previous_page_number }}">Prev</a></li>
            {% endif %}

            {% for pg in page_range %}
                {% if cves.number == pg %}
                    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ pg }}" class="btn btn-default">{{ pg }}</a></li>
                {% else %}
                    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ pg }}" class="btn">{{ pg }}</a></li>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}

            {% if cves.has_next %}
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ cves.next_page_number }}">Next</a></li>
                <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ cves.paginator.num_pages }}">Last &raquo;</a></li>
            {% endif %}
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <br/><br/>
</center>
{% endblock %}
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I got the fix! I added this code in the href element of the pagination.

```
&searched={{ searched }}
```

For example:

```
href="?page=1&searched={{ searched }}
```